# How to exclude references to songs/films in Google search results?

Tags: google-search

For example, i type in a phrase "times are getting harder" in Google search bar and expect to find some essays/articles about how the times are getting harder economically, etc., but all the search results (at least in the first page) show me references to some song with the title "Times Are Getting Harder", which is of no interest to me. Is it possible to filter this out somehow?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify search-terms you want to exclude by prefixing them with a dash (`-`).

For example you can search for: `"time are getting harder" -lyrics -song -movie`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the advanced google search that might help you.

Visit google.com, then from bottom right corner click on setting and select advanced search.

or directly use this link- "[https://www.google.com/advanced_search?hl=en-IN&fg=1][1]".

Hope this will help you.
Peace!!